# How to print last deleted element from the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
l=[1,2,3,4]
del l[0]
print(l)
#del l[0]
#want to print this number whenever it will be deleted from the list
```

How to print last deleted element from the list ?

Comment: "want to print this number whenever it will be deleted from the list" makes no sense. How can you know when a particular value has been deleted from a list unless you write code to do so. Don't forget that lists can contain duplicate values

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
my_list = [1, 2, 5, 8, 15, 25]

deleted_elements = []
deleted_elements.append(my_list.pop())
deleted_elements.append(my_list.pop())
deleted_elements.append(my_list.pop())

print(my_list)
print(deleted_elements)

print("Last deteleted: " + str(deleted_elements[-1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `pop` returns and removes an item of the list. So you could do this instead:

```
l=[1,2,3,4]
print(l.pop(0))
```